# Need help writing loop to display posts by categories in separate divs

Tags: posts, categories, query-posts

Total newb to WP codex. Below is what I'm attempting (the comments describe what I want the loop to do). Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<!-- if there are posts in category slug A, show div below -->
<div>
    <h3>Category Name of slug A</h3>
    <ul>
        <!-- for each post in category slug A, create a li -->
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


<!-- if there are posts in category slug B, show div below -->
<div>
    <h3>Category Name of slug B</h3>
    <ul>
        <!-- for each post in category slug B, create a li -->
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to show one post from each category?

Comment: all posts from each category.